# C program outputting strange "ur message" while trying to use sockets

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm new to C programming and I've been trying to write a program to send a message to itself, receive the message, and send one back. I found an [example](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html) of a client and server program and basically just copied it, trying to make a few changes. The program not only crashes, but outputs "ur message." Nowhere in the code is the string "ur message," so how is it possible that it outputs this every time?

I apologize for pasting a large amount of code, I just do not know where the problem is and I don't want to leave anything that might be relevant out. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <string.h>

#include <pthread.h>

char *write_buffer_to_port(char *host, int portno);
char *listen_on_port(int portno);
void* listen_thread(void *arg);
char *buffer_a;
char *buffer_b;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    buffer_a = "test";
    buffer_b = "";
    pthread_t tid[2];
    pthread_create(&(tid[1]), NULL, &listen_thread, NULL);
    printf("%s",write_buffer_to_port("localhost", 5737));
}

char *write_buffer_to_port(char *host, int portno) {
    int sockfd, n;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) exit(1);

    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) exit(2);

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
     (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
     server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) exit(3);
    n = write(sockfd, buffer_a, strlen(buffer_a));
    if (n < 0) exit(4);

    n = read(sockfd, &buffer_a, 255);
    if (n < 0) exit(5);
    close(sockfd);
    return (char *)buffer_a;
}

char *listen_on_port(int portno) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, clilen;

     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) exit(1);
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
                        sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) exit(2);
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) exit(3);
     //bzero(buffer_a,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,&buffer_b,255);
     if (n < 0) exit(4);
     //printf("Here is the message: %s\n",(char *)&buffer_b);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) exit(5);
    return (char *)&buffer_b;
}

void* listen_thread(void *arg) {
    printf("rcvd: %s\n",listen_on_port(5737));
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I always wonder why you newbie guys start with such complex stuff (multithreaded client/server). If (trying to?) becoming a mechanical engineer you wouldn't start with a rocket, not even with a plane, but perhaps with a bicycle or a go-card ..., wouldn't you?

Comment: @alk True, but I find it extremely difficult to be motivated to build something I don't want. Why not work on an interesting project and take the necessary tangents to learn what you need to on the way? It might take you a long time to build whatever it is, but at the end of the day you'll end up with a cool project and some pretty good skills. And I'm not new to programming, just C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ur message" is the end of "I got your message".

You aren't using `buffer_a` and `buffer_b` correctly. The way you have them declared, they are pointers to `char`. When you execute `read(fd, &buffer_b, 255)`, you're reading into the memory occupied by the pointer `buffer_b`, not into some buffer.

If you want to read into a buffer, you need to either declare the buffer as an object that has some space for you to read into, or declare it as a pointer and call `malloc` to allocate memory for it. If you declare the buffers as `char buffer_a[256]`, you will be able to read into them. That declaration reserves 256 bytes, and `buffer_a` is the address of the beginning of that memory. You could then do `read(fd, buffer_a, sizeof(buffer_a))` to read into the buffer.

I see that you're initializing `buffer_a` to a string that you're going to write, which you could still do if you were declaring it as an array, but it would be simpler to just write the string itself.

Comment: Ah ok. The original code was buffer[256], but I changed it because I couldn't print or return it. How do I have a function return a char[256]?

Comment: The function would return `char *` (the name of an array of `char` behaves like a constant `char *`).

Answer (score 0):

You're using unallocated buffers,
char *buffer_a; char *buffer_b;
So to fix it either allocate (malloc) it at main or declare them as arrays.